# Large bottom margin on github pages / jekyll blog

Tags: html, css, jekyll, github-pages, hyde

I'm struggling to fix a bug in my [GitHub Pages site](https://rgriff23.github.io/index.html). There is an enormous amount of white space in the margin below my pages. I  tried setting the bottom margins to 0 everywhere I can in the CSS files and still this large bottom margin shows up. How can I reduce the bottom margins?

The code is on GitHub:

https://github.com/rgriff23/rgriff23.github.io

Comment: `.content {margin-bottom: 0;}` should fix your problem. I'd also add `.sidebar {overflow: auto}` to that (unless you actually like those useless scrollbars on your sidebar). You should load this CSS after `hide.css`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I think it would be better to amend his existing rulesets rather than overwriting them later with no use of the previous values.

Comment: It's not *his* existing rulesets. It's an existing jekyll theme. I'm assuming they might want to be able to update it without having to do all the mods again, that's why I suggest a separate stylesheet with the mods.

Comment: Awesome and thanks so much for the tip about the scrollbar. I'm told unsolicited advice is often the best, so I try to pay attention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to remove `margin-bottom` rule from your `.content` class styling or at least reduce it to your preference.

Due to the media queries, there are two locations where you have to amend this: in your `hyde.css` file, the rulesets are located at line 98 and 107.